# Does there exists known special cases of a zero Riemann tensor for 3D metrics?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, conformal-geometry, dimensional-analysis

In two dimensions, if one has a flat metric $g_{ab}$, then one can transform $g_{ab}$ to another flat metric $h_{ab}=e^{2\varphi}g_{ab}$, when $\nabla^2 \varphi =0$ and the Riemann tensor remains zero.

Does there exists known special cases of a zero Riemann tensor for 3D metrics?

Comment: This question needs some clarification: by "the coordinate system is flat" do you mean "the metric $\tilde g$ is flat"?

Comment: Also explain your reasoning in a bit more detail - it seems you're identifying the rightmost parenthetical with $\Delta e^{\pm \phi}$ (check your sign convention for the Laplacian here, I think you might have used the opposite one to the wiki article), but how are you dealing with the central term?

Comment: This result is probably pretty useless even if true - assuming your flat manifold is complete, every positive harmonic function is a constant.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I made a mistake earlier. I read the central term too fast, and I thought it said $\nabla_i \varphi \partial_j \varphi - \partial_i \varphi \partial_j \varphi$ which is zero in a cartensian coordinate system, however this is not the case. I do have another question.